# Extract to sqlite db from R: Renaming row_name column

Tags: r, sqlite, r-dbi

I'm writing to sqlite db from R using the following command:

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'topics',as.data.frame(topics), row.names = NA, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE, field.types = NULL)
```

I get the following table in sqlite:
[image]

How can I rename the row_names attribute?

The df [as.data.frame(topics)] snippet is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `row.names` argument to `dbWriteTable` is for: Set it to a character value to rename the column, set it to `NULL` to avoid writing it altogether. Explore the [`guessRowName()` function](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI/blob/bf12f77ce23c2e8444ecea2bf000d8a404944185/R/rownames.R#L68) in the `DBI` package for other options.